# SQL for oracle query get time most service bookings are booked

Tags: sql, oracle, time, service, timestamp

im try to write a query for when the most popular booking_time of a service is. or when are more services required?
The booking time is in a time stamp data type like this: '09-JAN-20 09.00.00.000000 AM' and I know that most bookings are at 0900 but how do I draw that element out, without changing the table.
The table is 'Orders' and the column is 'Booking_time'

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break down the bookings by hour, you can use `to_char()` or `extract()` and then aggregate:

```
select to_char(booking_time, 'HH24:00') as hh, count(*)
from t
group by to_char(booking_time, 'HH24:00')
order by hh desc;
```

Comment: That was my first ever question. I'm sorry I didn't know there was an accept. for a future reader I changed the order by to order by count (*) desc; to get the most used hour at the top. worked brilliantly. Thank you @GordonLinoff I have a question ready for tomorrow, I have been stuck for weeks. You saved my sanity.